# Pycharm does not find system variables set via bashrc export

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, pycharm, environment-variables

I have set environment variables in the .bashrc:

```
export nnUNet_preprocessed="/data/nnUnet/preprocessed"
```

These are found successfully in terminal after sourcing and/or logging out. If I run pycharm out of the same terminal, it is able to find them via

```
nnUNet_preprocessed = os.environ.get('nnUNet_preprocessed')
```

However, if I launch Pycharm via Actions (Ubuntu 16.04), it yields none. Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to relaunch your shell after changing the `.bashrc`

Comment: I don't know what _Actions_ is, but how do you ensure, that your .bashrc has been processed when this _Actions_ is being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *~/.bashrc* init script is only run by interactive Bash shells. When you launch PyCharm using your window manager there isn't any Bash shell, let alone an interactive one, involved in lauching PyCharm. You can set the env var globally (e.g., in */etc/environment*) but why not just start PyCharm from an interactive Bash session if it requires custom env vars you want to manage in your *~/.bashrc* init script? Alternatively, create a wrapper script that looks something like the following and run it via "Actions" (whatever that is):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -i
exec Pycharm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your pycharm and it will reload your system environment. You can check the environment in here to check if it is the latest variables:

[image]

If you don't want to restart your Pycharm,you can just set variables in this [User environment varisbles].

Comment: This didn't help. It seems, Pycharm has to be run from shell to inherit its variables. Running from an icon doesn't work.